# SQL Query to exclude any items that meet a certain requirement (accounting for null)

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

I see similar questions but not one that answers exactly this case, so I will go ahead and ask.

I need to select a group of facilities, but once they've matched a certain set of criteria, they may *not* be included.  So if the submission month matches a particular month and either FacWideAU, FacWideAR, or AU = 1 (not 0 or null), then that facility cannot be included.  The facilities may have multiple results.

```
Sample DB Example (only Hosp1 should qualify):

 HospID  |  HospName        |        FacWideAU   |  FacWideAR  |  AU
 ---------------------------------------------------------------
 1          Hosp1                    0
 2          Hosp2                    1             0            0
 2          Hosp2                    0                          0
 3          Hosp3                    1             1            0
 3          Hosp3                   
 3          Hosp3                    0
```

etc.

Is there an easier way to write the query than the following (repeating all the selection logic, which has joins and is more convoluted in reality)?

Many thanks!

```
   Select distinct HospID, HospName
      from <Hospital Table>
      where Description='...whatever...'
      etc.

   and ID NOT in
   (
      Select distinct HospID 
         from <Hospital Table>
         where Description='...whatever...'
         etc.

         and (case when (TO_CHAR(SubmissionMonth, 'MON-YYYY') = 'Mar-2017' AND
         (FacWideAU = 1 or FacWideAR = 1 or AU = 1)) then 1 else 0 end) = 1
   )
```

Comment: @D Stanley Thanks for editing...I know that came out a mess!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: I didn't include it because it's Intersystems Cache SQL, which no one else ever heard of.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found another solution: You could use a left join on your table.

```
Select distinct h1.HospID, h1.HospName
      from <Hospital Table> h1
      left join <Hospital Table> h2 on h1.HospId = h2.HospId
            and (((TO_CHAR(h2.SubmissionMonth, 'MON-YYYY') = 'Mar-2017')
            and (isnull(h2.FacWideAU, 0) = 1 or isnull(h2.FacWideAR, 0) = 1 or isnull(h2.AU, 0) = 1))

      where Description='...whatever...'
      and h2.id is null
      etc.
```

Comment: There will be a ton of hospitals, though.

Comment: You don't have to this for each hospital seperatly, this will handle all of them.

Comment: I think this may be too specific a problem to really work in this forum or to be of much use to anyone else.  I appreciate your help and efforts on this, though!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a null check to each column:

```
where FacWideAU IS NULL 
   or FacWideAU = 1 
   or FacWideAR IS NULL
   or FacWideAR = 1 
   or AU IS NULLor AU = 1
```

Comment: ...or maybe `where isnull(FacWideAU, 1 ) = 1 or isnull(FacWideAr, 1 ) = 1 or isnull(AU,1 ) = 1`  -- to the same effect

Comment: @D Stanley, I'm not following your thought.  What I need is to find the hospitals where FacWideAU, FacWideAR, and AU are *never* true...bearing in mind that the hospitals may have cases where one of those items is true and cases where none of them is true.  Once one of them is true, they cannot be included in the list of hospitals.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the `not in` part and change your original `where` part:

```
where Description='...whatever...'
   and ((TO_CHAR(SubmissionMonth, 'MON-YYYY') != 'Mar-2017')
   or (FacWideAU IS NULL 
   and FacWideAU = 0 
   and FacWideAR IS NULL
   and FacWideAR = 0
   and AU IS NULL
   and AU = 0))
```

Comment: Thanks, Kevin...I don't want to find the ones that qualify, exactly.  I want to find the ones that have never been *disqualified*, if that makes sense.

Comment: Is it possible to extend your sample DB example with the 'SubmissionMonth' column so it is easier to see why only hosp1 should qualify?
At the moment with the my criteria rows 1, 3, 5 and 6 should qualify (without a SubmissionMonth).

Comment: Hosp2 doesn't qualify because one of those flags is true in the second row, and Hosp3 doesn't qualify because one of those flags is true in the fourth row.  It's not a case of certain *rows* qualifying...it's a case of the entire hospital qualifying because none of its rows were disqualified.

Comment: Ah now I get it.
In that case I'm affraid you will have to use the repeated selection logic.